# What is the difference between hot spring water and regular hot water?

Tags: konosuba

In the last arc of KonoSuba season 2, Aqua winds up purifying the hot spring water, turning it into "regular hot water".

What is the difference between hot spring water and "regular hot water"?

The only clue I can see is that it's (hot spring water) animated green instead of clear or bluish clear (regular water).

Comment: Generally hot springs are considered to have water with purifying qualities since its from mountains and forests. And regular hot water is just... Normal hot water.

Comment: does Aqua "purifiy" Hot Spring Water into Normal Hot Water? because that sounds like the total opposite of what normally happens and how you describe the change of water does suggests the opposite (in some anime Hotsprings Water is green and normal water is blue/clear)

Comment: @Memor-X idk how you interpreted it 180 degrees from what I said, but I added some notes to make it clearer.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser *"turning it (hot spring water) into "regular hot water"."* is how i did, as if it was hot spring water at first then was chnaged to regular water

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be looking for something that's analogous to 温泉 (*onsen*) vs 銭湯 (*sentō*) in Japan.

By definition, *onsen* is hot spring water which (supposedly) contains minerals and other things that makes the bath more healthy and provide relaxation benefits (animated green in KonoSuba), while *sentō* is normal heated tap water (animated blue).

Aqua purifying the *onsen* water would have implied that she had taken out all the "impurities" (i.e. the beneficial minerals) in the water, and leaving it with the inferior "just hot water."

Regarding animation, it's not always consistent that *onsen* water is colored green.