# How do the citizens of Arcanretia know that Aqua purified their hot springs?

Tags: konosuba

Starting in [s02e09](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_KonoSuba_episodes), Aqua is accused of purifying the hot springs in Arcanretia.  In the meta sense, we can tell the difference by the animated color (green for hot spring, clear/blue for regular water), and that Aqua is known to be able to purify water simply by wading into it, as we learned in s01e05.

It's never mentioned how any of the citizens would know that.  Here in reality, mineral water is the same color as tap water.

How would the citizens of Arcanretia know that the hot spring water was purified into regular water?

**Note:** This is a followup question to [What is the difference between hot spring water and regular hot water?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47214/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-spring-water-and-regular-hot-water), not a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, hot spring water usually *does* show a subtle, if not significant, difference in color as compared to normal hot water.

Referring back to my [previous answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47214/what-is-the-difference-between-hot-spring-water-and-regular-hot-water/47220#47220) of how in Arcanretia, hot spring water vs normal hot water is analogous to *onsen* vs *sentō*, if you were to look at stock photos of *onsen* baths, you could see that the water is somewhat cloudy and unclear:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hikyou.jp](https://www.hikyou.jp/img2/R1555723592943a_FWx800_5557255519bf4.jpg))</sub>

You can probably tell the difference between that kind of water and clear, normal hot water.

Comment: So, apparently there are different color onsen too.  I did a quick search to see if the color above was normal or just a special case.  I'm going to say that the colored water is a clear indicator that it's onsen.  https://japanese-products.blog/2018/05/09/onsen-colors-meaning/

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser There are other colored onsen as well, for example the sulfur-containing white onsen.